# Error creating table in MYSQL using Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I am trying to create a MySQL table using python but it keeps giving me this error: Error while connecting to MySQL 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ' close FLOAT, high FLOAT, low FLOAT, open FLOAT, volume FLOAT, instrument CHA...' at line 1

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error

#connecting to database
try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host = "localhost",
                                         user = "root",
                                         database="hindalco"
                                         )

    #cursor method used to perform SQL operations
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE tickersymbol (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, datetime smalldatetime, close FLOAT, high FLOAT, low FLOAT, open FLOAT, volume FLOAT, instrument CHAR(10)")


#print error messages using error as object
except Error as e:
    print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)

#close open connections after work is complete
finally:
    if connection.is_connected():
        connection.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

Comment: `datetime` is a type and likely a reserved keyword. `smalldatetime` is not a type in mariadb (I beleive it's a type in sql server). Maybe instead: `date_time datetime`.

Comment: I just tried this. Still giving me this error :   Error while connecting to MySQL 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

It is because there is no such data type as `smalldatetime`. You probably meant to say:

```
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE tickersymbol (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, smalldatetime datetime, close FLOAT, high FLOAT, low FLOAT, open FLOAT, volume FLOAT, instrument CHAR(10)")
```

#### Comment follow-up.

To use mariadb connector, you would do something like this:

```
import mariadb as mdb

dbconfig = {
    'host': 'localhost',
    'user': 'username',
    'password': 'password',
    'database': 'dbname'
}

try:
    db = mdb.connect(**dbconfig)
except mdb.Error as e:
    raise(f'error connecting: {e}')

# A matter of personal preference, I like queries to be returned as dictionaries, and I like auto-commits to the database:
cursor = db.cursor(dictionary=True)
db.autocommit = True
```

At this point the `cursor.execute()` line should work fine.

Comment: I'm still getting an error :   Error while connecting to MySQL 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: What is the error when you run the command in mysql directly? I'm using mariadb 15.1 and it works fine.

Comment: I just ran it through mysql directly and it worked. I just wonder why it isn't going through using Python.

Comment: I'm using mariadb connector (`pip install mariadb`) and it works like a charm. I'll edit my response to include that information.

Comment: I just figured out the problem. I forgot a closing bracket at the end of the CREATE TABLE query. Thanks for all your help.